# Don't see all content of my folder

Tags: atom-editor

In my atom when I add a project, it does not display all content (I mean files and folders)) into it.
F.x. on screen below http folder is full of files/folders.

What could be a reason of that?

I've Mac + Atom 1.0.15 (but it started from very long time ago).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Permissions, possibly.

Comment: @Jongware: well, but I'm as a user see files in Finder.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I've had the same issue recently. With one of the new versions of Atom, a setting was enabled that I had never changed, causing some files to not show up any more.

The setting is *Hide VCS Ignored Files*, which can be found in the *Packages / Tree View* settings:

[image: Tree View Settings]

Make sure this setting is disabled (i.e. unchecked). When it is checked, it will not show files that are *ignored* by Git. I noticed a `.gitignore` file in your first screenshot - that could be causing it.

The setting one above this (*Hide Ignored Names*) could also be relevant, but I'm not entirely sure what it does.

Anyway, the *Hide VCS Ignored Files* was enabled in one of my workspaces for some reason, and it caused a similar issue as you described. It's probably worth a try...

Comment: thanks, once I unchecked that property - it started to work.

Comment: Note the difference between the global *Hide VCS Ignored Files* (not what you want) and the tree-view's *Hide VCS Ignored Files* (that's the one).  [They are separate settings](http://blog.lukebennett.com/2015/09/21/show-hidden-files-in-atom-sidebar/).  Had me stumped for a bit!

Comment: @EdwardNewell Your response worked for me! I already had the `Settings > Core Settings > Exclude VCS Ignored Paths` unchecked, but totally overlooked the `Settings > Packages > Core Packages > Tree View > Hide VCA Ignored Files` settings. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just wanted to mention, that it can be toggled by pressing `i` in the tree-view